# Beautifulsoup scrape not showing everything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the img tag from the first image, so I can get the image link.
When I scrape the site with beautifulsoup, there is not a img tag (in image 2).

[image: The html that I want to scrape]

[image: Scraped with beautifulsoup]

[image]

I don't understand why the website has an img tag for each, but beautifulsoup does not.

Comment: Some of your code would be helpful.

Comment: Can you try printing the code from just one element in all_prod and see if it shows what you are looking for? 

Try:
print(str(all_prod[0]))

Comment: I tried to print the first index, but it does not return the img tag. It has everything from one of the li tags except the img. I have done the same thing on ebay and some other sites and had no issues.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the images does not load on the site until it gets input from the user.

For example, if you had to click a dropdown or a next arrow to view the image on the website, then it is probably making a new request for that image and updating the html on the site.

Another issue might be JavaScript. Websites commonly have JavaScript code that runs after the page has first been loaded. The Javascript then mades additional requests to update elements on the page.

To see what is happending on the site, in your browers go to the site press F12. Go to the Network tab and reload the page. You will see all the urls that are requested.

If you need to get data that loads by Javascript requests, try using Selenium.

### UPDATE

I went to the webiste you posted and pulled just the html using the following code.

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://auburn.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=test")
print(page.text)
```

The requests return the html you would get before any Javascript and other requests run. You can see it [here](https://pastebin.com/4iFwxi30)

The image urls are not in this either. This means that in the initial request the image html is not returned. What we do see are data tags, see line 2192 of the pastebin. These are commonly used by JavaScript to make additional requests so it knows which images to go and get.

Result: The img tags you are looking for are not in the html returned from your request. Selenium will help you here, or investigate how thier javascript is using those data-ids to determine which images to request.

Comment: I tried what you said and there was some javascript before the loading images, but I compared it to a scrape of eBay that I have already done. It looks like they do the same thing.